# Parts of tensorflow codes cannot be directed to by Go To Declaration

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

I am using pycharm to program a deep learning code. However, I found that some parts of Tensorflow library are not accessible by Go To Declaration in Pycharm.

For example, the following one if I try to go to declaration of `Attentionwrapper` or `seq2seq`

```
tf.contrib.seq2seq.AttentionWrapper
```

would have error as `"cannot find declaration to go"`. But it works if I only choose to go to declaration of `contrib`

I wonder why that happens and how I should fix this ?